# Capybara. How to check a checkbox generated in a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, rspec, capybara

I want to test my application using Capybara. User checks some tables, hits confirm and application shows the message. But I cann't access any checkbox generated in a loop.

> index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@user, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
 ......
<div id="tables" class="transitions-enabled">
  <% @tables.each do |table| %>
      ......
      <%= label_tag 'table-check-box-' + table.id.to_s, 'Apply for table ' + table.id.to_s %>
      <%= check_box_tag 'user[poker_table_ids][]', table.id, nil, id: ('table-check-box-' + table.id.to_s) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

> index.html generated from index.html.erb

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="new_user" action="/users" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="YSbO1s8fXdB9oKDaN49GQJwg09W7ZnJSAui+hNDkoD/g3T3RPoM/HsAEftnzVk2Ss/Y0VpDzA58g80j2t9c9rQ==" />
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
  <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="user[email]" />
    <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit for Tables" id="submit" class="btn btn-default" />
  </div>
</div>

<br>

<div id="tables" class="transitions-enabled">
      <div class="box panel panel-default">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <h3>|15| Table 1</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
            <p>2016/2/10</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
            <p>Starts at 20:40</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
            <p>Players: 1</p>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
                <label for="table-check-box-15">Apply for table 15</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="user[poker_table_ids][]" id="table-check-box-15" value="15" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

> submit_for_tables_spec.rb

```
...
scenario 'should submit for tables' do
   visit root_path
   fill_in 'Email', with: 'test@gmail.com'
   check('Apply for table 15')
   click_on('Submit for Tables')
   expect(page).to have_content('Tables were successfully assigned')
end
```

When I run this test, it says:
Failure/Error: check('Apply for table 15')
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find checkbox "Apply for table 15". Table with id - 15 exists. Can you guys help me with this problem?

Comment: I suspect you are missing a space character in your 'Apply for table' string, so instead of labeling it "Apply for table 15" you are labeling it "Apply for table15".

Comment: shoover, thanks for answerig, but I accidentally missed a space while posting this question. The problem is still here. When I add a check_box_tag outside of the loop, capybara can find it, but inside of the loop - cann't

Comment: Post the actual html generated instead of the erb

Comment: Are you hiding the checkboxes, and just styling the labels to show the checked/unchecked state?

Comment: Tom Walpole, no, I do not

Answer (score 0):

You can try selecting checkbox using one of the method mentioned below:

```
within(#tables)
  check('Apply for table 15')
end
```

OR

```
within(.transitions-enabled)
  check('Apply for table 15')
end
```

OR

```
find(:css, "#table-check-box-15").set(true)
```

OR

```
page.execute_script("$('#table-check-box-15').prop('checked', true);")
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: None of this worked for me. I'm working on Windows and cann't install capybara-webkit, so, I suppose, that's why I'm facing this problem